# Nodejs instalacion de Dependencias

Tags: javascript, nodejs, express, instalacion, dependencias

tengo una duda, cuando instalo por ejemplo express me sale una flecha hacia arriba:

```
"express": "^4.17.1"
```

que significa "^" ?
gracias

Comment: Es para especificar que puede ser cualquier versión `4`, a partir de `4.17.1`, por ejemplo: `4.17.5` o `4.20.1`, pero no `5.0.1`. Más información en: https://semver.npmjs.com/#how

Comment: muchas gracias!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

esos caracteres opcionales   definen como debe ser tratada esa dependencia la próxima vez que se corra npm install en el proyecto:

- Si la versión tiene un ^: busca una versión compatible con la que está definida
  ahí.
- Si la versión tiene un ~: busca una versión lo más cercana posible a la definida.

---

Dejo la fuente, que se inspiro en la documentacion oficial
[package.json](https://medium.com/noders/t%C3%BA-yo-y-package-json-9553929fb2e3)

Comment: muchas gracias!